# Covering of a Riemannian Symmetric Space

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, lie-groups

We know that universal covering of a complete locally symmetric space is a symmetric space
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_space). Let $(N, \pi)$ be a covering manifold of
a symmetric space $M$. Is it true that $N$ is a Riemannaian symmetric space ? Kindly provide your answer with proof or reference.
?